# I put caulking in between tiles that had grout already underneath it. What do I do?

Tags: bathroom, tile, floor, grout, caulking

My floor tiles had unsealed grout already in between the tiles. I went to Home Depot and bought a “sealant”, but it was actually caulking. I ended up putting caulk over top the unsealed grout in between all of my tiles.

I realized later that, this is not how you seal grout. I’d rather not scrape the caulking off of the grout. Is there anything else I can do. Can I seal the caulk over the top of grout in between the tiles?

Comment: It sounds like you have already sealed the caulk overtop the grout in between the tiles, have you not?  Are you asking what the long term result of using caulking will be or are you asking how to remove it?

Comment: You can get a caulking remover spray.  It has extremely varied results.  Some types of caulking you spray it a few times and leave it for a while and the old caulk will come off in one nice rubbery strip, and sometimes it does nothing.  I'm guessing the edges of the tile were both clean and porous, so if you squeezed the caulking in there you probably got an extremely good bond.

Comment: I'd say the grout is actually pretty well sealed at this point, and leave it alone. If (or maybe more accurately, "when") it starts to peel and look bad, do what @KH suggested and try some of the caulk remover. Let it sit and bake for a while, and then see if it peels off. If it doesn't peel, you're going to need a good stiff bristled brush and a rainy afternoon to spend scrubbing.